# Bootstrap Custom Plugin - Getter Method

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to write a Bootstrap 3 Custom plugin for a Wizard. I am doing ok so far, but I am having difficulty creating a method to return the currently active page.

I would hope to do the following:

```
var activePage = $('#wizard').wizard("getActivePage"); // should return the page number
```

I have adapter the example found in the standard Bootstrap code:

From:

```
if (typeof option == 'string') data[option](args);
```

To:

```
if (typeof option == 'string') return data[option](args);
```

And have a function in the code of:

```
getActivePage() {
    return this.currentPage;
}
```

However, it is returning a JQuery object rather than the page number.

Is there a way to do this or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Give some detailed code were the currentpage variable and getactivepage defined

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After thinking about this for a bit longer, I realised that the default functionality of the Plugin function is the issue as it is returning the JQuery chain (apologies, the following uses some Typescript):

I originally had:

```
function Plugin(option, args) {

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('xyz.wizard');
        var options = $.extend(option, Wizard.DEFAULTS) as WizardOptions;

        if (!data) {
            data = new Wizard(this, options);
            $this.data('xyz.wizard', data);
        }
        if (typeof option === 'string') return data[option](args);
    });
}
```

and then added a new part at the top:

```
function Plugin(option, args) {

    // New Part - If option is a string, then call the named method and return the result
    if (typeof option === 'string') {
        var data = $(this).data('xyz.wizard');
        if(data) {
            return data[option](args);
        }
    }

    // Otherwise do the default
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('xyz.wizard');
        var options = $.extend(option, Wizard.DEFAULTS) as WizardOptions;

        if (!data) {
            data = new Wizard(this, options);
            $this.data('xyz.wizard', data);
        }
        // if (typeof option === 'string') return data[option](args);
    });
}
```

It does seem to work but I'm not sure if it is the correct approach.